# fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Invalid argument

Tags: reactjs, github, npm, github-pages

I am trying to deploy my react app on git pages and i get the following error.

bash: /dev/tty: No such device or address
error: failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1)
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Invalid argument

I tried to setting origin url with my username and password but that does not help.

Any pointer would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be solved by adding user name in {project}/.git/config file. Just like this :

[remote "origin"]
      url = `http://<username>@<IP_address>/Shared/Infrastructure.git/`

Please note the single quotation and remove <> in original command.

Alternatively,  you should try to set global user name & pwd first